# How to prevent Vista from entering Sleep mode when certain conditions exist?

Tags: windows, sleep, hdmi

Mainly, I would like to prevent my laptop from entering Sleep mode when I am playing music or streaming video.  This is on my laptop, so another option that would work would be to prevent sleep mode whenever the laptop is plugged into my tv via HDMI (ie when HDMI port is in use).  Or prevent sleep mode whenever there is audio playing..
I am soon upgrading to Windows 7, so solutions using 7 would be great also/instead.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download/install/run [Caffeine](http://download.cnet.com/Caffeine/3000-2094_4-10914397.html)

See [this](http://www.ghacks.net/2008/07/27/use-caffeine-to-keep-your-pc-awake/) post for more info

It basically simulates a mouse-click after x amount of inactivity time to prevent your pc from nodding off.